# How to properly use Fortran shared object in R package

Tags: r, fortran, package

I'm writing an R package with the help of `devtools`.
I have a R function which uses Fortran subroutines (called with `.Fortran()` function) from a `packagename.so` file located in the `src` folder. 
I put `@useDynLib packagename` in R/packagename.R and ran `devtools::document()` to add useDynLib(packagename) to NAMESPACE but when I run `devtools::check()` an error occures.
I read the *R packages* documentation and googled the question but I haven't found a solution yet.

Two related questions come to my mind:

- do I need the Fortran source code and let R compile it?
- should the shared object have the same name of the package or not?

**TL;DR** 
How do I get rid of the following error after running `devtools::check()`?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROCkerMeth’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):                                                                                          
    shared object ‘ROCkerMeth.so’ not found
```

Comment: I think you are mixing things here. useDynLib would be for what is generated from your package’s source, whereas you would rather use a pre-compiled outside library, which you may want to name differently than your package and place somewhere under inst/lib(s)